# Biblatex: authoryear style with full date instead of year only

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm trying to use the authoryear-icomp style with full date (if available) instead of year only. With this MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,oneside,ngerman]{article}

\let\mkccitation\mkcitation

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-icomp,
maxbibnames=2,            % maximale Namen, die im Literaturverzeichnis angezeigt werden
maxcitenames=2,            % maximale Namen, die im Text angezeigt werden, ab 3 wird u.a. nach den ersten Autor angezeigt
idemtracker=constrict,
ibidtracker=constrict,
pagetracker=true,
ibidpage=true,
isbn=false,
alldates=comp,
dateabbrev=true,
sortcites=true,
mergedate=compact,
datelabel=comp,
block=space,
mincrossrefs=6
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
        @book{book1,
    author = {{Some Author}},
    date = {2013},
    title = {{Some Title}},
    url = {http://www.someurl.com},
    address = {Somewhere},
    urldate = {2015-08-19},
    publisher = {{Any Publisher}},
    institution = {{Any Institution}}
}   
@misc{misc1,
    author = {{Some Author}},
    date = {2013-06-09},
    title = {{Some Other Title}},
    url = {http://www.anyurl.net},
    urldate = {2015-05-31}
}   
@misc{misc2,
    author = {{Some Author}},
    date = {2013-06-09},
    title = {{Not The Same Title}},
    url = {http://www.anyurl.net},
    urldate = {2015-05-21}
}   
@misc{misc3,
    author = {{Some Author}},
    date = {2013-01-03},
    title = {{Any Title}}
}   
@misc{misc4,
    author = {{Some Author}},
    date = {2014-01-01},
    title = {{Anything}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{jobname}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{url={Online}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{urlseen = {zuletzt gepr\"uft am}}

\AtEveryBibitem{
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
}



%%%
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {%
        \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printdatelabel\printfield{extrayear}}% 
    }%
}

%\AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{day}{}{\clearfield{extrayear}}{}}
%\AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldundef{day}{}{\clearfield{extrayear}}{}}


\begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{ngerman}

    \parencite{book1}
    \parencite{misc1}
    \parencite{misc2}
    \parencite{misc3}
    \parencite{misc4}

    \printbibliography[title=References]

\end{document}
```

which gives the following output at the time:
[image: output1]

it is at least close to what I need. But I would like to get rid of all unnecessary extrayear labels. When using

```
    \AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{day}{}{\clearfield{extrayear}}{}}
    \AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldundef{day}{}{\clearfield{extrayear}}{}}
```

The output reads:

[image: output2]

I would like the labels to look like:
(Some Author 2013) (Some Author 9. Juni 2013a) (Some Author 9. Juni
2013b) (Some Author 3. Jan. 2013) (Some Author 1. Jan. 2014)

Is there any way to achieve the desired labeling?

Comment: As far as I can see the `extrayear` only ever makes  `labelname`+`labelyear` unique, `labelmonth` and `labelday` don't play a role in this. From what I have seen so far, one would have to implement such a solution in Biber, as that is where these disambiguation features are dealt with.

Comment: Indeed the internal disambiguation strings in Biber look like this `279331e1f2c7fe5eb620b4bc15532064,2013`. Where the first part is the name hash and the second the `labelyear`, `labelmonth` and `labelday` are never taken into account. Seeing this, it might be straightforward to implement this in Biber. But one would have to give some thought to corner cases, though. Maybe you can give the developers a call with a feature request over at github (for [Biber](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/), for [`biblatex`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues)).

Comment: Why do you desire such a labeling? I find it quite unreadable.

Comment: This is quite dissapointing somehow. :( So, I need some workaround... my best idea is to use
        \AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldundef{userb}{}{\clearfield{extrayear}}{}}
        \AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{userb}{}{\clearfield{extrayear}}{}}
and a field userb = {del} at entries book1 and misc3. Only problem is, that the two remaining extrayear labels read b and c instead of a and b. I could use sortname = {{Some Author zz}} alongside with the userb fields. This gives the right labeling but a wrong ordering in the bibliography. Any other ideas?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it's wanted for newspaper articles mainly.

Comment: As far as I can tell it is going to be very hard to such a thing if the order of `extrayears` goes contrary to the ordering in the `bibliography`. You could try adding `sortyear` with to all of the entries influencing the sorting order, but that will probably end the same way as your `sortname` attempt.

Comment: I also find this scheme quite confusing.  It forces the user to process more information, and probably in most cases excess information (do we really need the exact date in a citation? If it is so important, explicitly mention it in the text). If you only print years and use another `mergedate` setting, no one will notice that you did not use the scheme you originally wanted to use.

Comment: Did you find any solution? If not, I'm pretty sure the best way is to start a feature request to make `extrayear` also respect `month` and `day` (if so desired), all other more or less ad-hoc solutions will have problems with corner cases as currently Biber only takes into account the year. (Almost all solutions will break if you have two works from say `2015-06-07` and two from `2015` only - you would essentially have to redo Biber's work to deal with that properly.)

Comment: Isn't this an exact duplicate of [biblatex: extrayear only if full date is equal?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169338/35864)?